# GoLand: Shortcut to move terminal to editor

Tags: jetbrains-ide, goland

I want to move the terminal to the editor when I open it. It is in the bottom and has a small height which is difficult to use and I have to clean a lot. It would be much better if the terminal is in the editor and I could move between editor tabs and terminal tabs. I can do so now but I have to right-click and select the option. It would be easier if there was a shortcut.

So does anyone know a way to set the shortcut or a plugin that allows you to set the shortcut for a task, that would be very helpful. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well... "Move to Editor" is already an action in the Terminal tab menu. Therefore you can assign a shortcut to that action in a standard way:

1. `Settings/Preferences | Keymap`
2. Locate that action -- will be under `Plugins | Terminal` node
3. Assign a desired shortcut.

[image]
*(The screenshot is from PhpStorm but there should be no major difference in GoLand for this settings screen)*

Comment: Thank you. Didn't know this.

Comment: I have to right-click on the terminal and then use the shortcut. Don't know why that's happening. Could you help me with this?

Comment: You do not need to right click. But the focus has to be in the Terminal. At very least that's how it works for me (I'm on Windows 10; PhpStorm 2020.3.3). Maybe that depends on what shortcut is used; what settings for the Terminal is (e.g. intercept shortcuts)

Comment: You can browse through these tickets: maybe you will find that matches your behaviour: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA?q=%23%7BTools.%20Terminal%7D%20shortcut

Comment: Okay, Thank you.